# Translation from LTL with Past to LTL

Tags: automata-theory, linear-temporal-logic

Has it been charaterized the cost of the translation from LTL with Past to LTL?

In [Gab89] this translation is assumed to be non elementary and in "Temporal Logic with Past is Exponentially More Succinct" is described a detour of complexity 3EXPTIME. But I haven't found any other tight constructions.